# LED Pin 13 Input or Output?

Tags: arduino-uno, led

It is not clear to me whether Pin 13, corresponding to the LED, should be driven by an external voltage or not.

From the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno),

> LED: 13. There is a built-in LED driven by digital pin 13. When the
>   pin is HIGH value, the LED is on, when the pin is LOW, it's off.

However, in the "Blink" example code I am running, the Pin 13 appears to be driven by the ATmega328:

```
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(100);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(2000);              // wait for a second
}
```

If I now attach a voltage source to Pin 13, will there be contention issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other I/O pin, there should be no problem driving this pin (and
thus the builtin LED) from an external source, as long as you make sure
it is in `INPUT` mode. If the pin is set to `OUTPUT` you will likely
damage the Arduino.

**Warning**: If you have the Blink example already loaded in the
Arduino, the pin is in output mode. Be sure to upload another program,
that does not set pin 13 to output, **before** connecting anything that
could drive pin 13.

Comment: It would be good defensive - and documentary - practice to explicitly set it to INPUT during setup() rather than depending on the default.